# Batch file to run exe if not running - how to add a switch or argument?

Tags: batch-file

Hi I have this batch file

```
@ECHO OFF

SET EXEName=pma_schd.exe
SET EXEFullPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Trace Solutions\TRAMPS\PMA\Win32\pma_schd.exe

TASKLIST | FINDSTR /I "%EXEName%"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :StartScheduler
GOTO EOF

:StartScheduler
START "" "%EXEFullPath%"
GOTO EOF
```

It checks to see if the program pma_schd.exe is running and if not runs it. However I need to add a switch /Main to the exe to tell it which database to look at - but this errors:

```
SET EXEFullPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Trace Solutions\TRAMPS\PMA\Win32\pma_schd.exe /Main
```

How can I add the switch /Main ??

Thanks

Comment: Try to use `SET EXEFullPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Trace Solutions\TRAMPS\PMA\Win32\pma_schd.exe" /Main`

or 

`SET EXEFullPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Trace Solutions\TRAMPS\PMA\Win32\pma_schd.exe /Main"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting `%EXEFullPath%` in double quotes in the `START` command, you are making everything in the variable into an element of the target executable path.

You need to remove `/Main` from `EXEFullPath`, as in your original definition, and add it to the `START` command:

```
START "" "%EXEFullPath%" /Main
```

If you need to parameterise the database name, use a separate parameter, eg:-

```
DBname=/Main
START "" "%EXEFullPath%" %DBname%
```